# I want to uninstall the monetdb before I install it again

Tags: sql, monetdb

what should I do? only remove the bin directory? or I need some extra operation?

Comment: Wich operating system? Windows? Linux? OSX? How did you install? From source? From binary tarball? From Fedora/Debian/Ubuntu package? Using installer? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reinstall except if you used a unique `--prefix` during `./configure`. If the latter is the case, the prefix can simply be removed.

In an empty prefix, I have the following files:

```
bin:
arraytest     Mfilter.py  mserver5     sample0  smack00        testgetinfo
malsample.pl  MkillUsers  msqldump     sample1  smack01        tomograph
Mapprove.py   Mlog        Mtest.py     sample2  sqlsample.php
mclient       monetdb     Mtimeout     sample3  sqlsample.pl
Mdiff         monetdbd    odbcsample1  sample4  stethoscope

etc:
tmpfiles.d

include:
monetdb

lib:
libbat.la         libmapi.so.7           libMonetODBC.la   libstream.so.6
libbat.so         libmapi.so.7.0.0       libMonetODBCs.la  libstream.so.6.0.0
libbat.so.11      libmonetdb5.la         libMonetODBC.so   monetdb5
libbat.so.11.0.1  libmonetdb5.so         libMonetODBCs.so  pkgconfig
libmapi.la        libmonetdb5.so.17      libstream.la      python2.7
libmapi.so        libmonetdb5.so.17.0.1  libstream.so      python3.3

lib64:
perl5

local:
share

share:
doc  man  monetdb  php

var:
monetdb5
```

So you could also try removing those. Be careful however, there are some subdirectories such as var, lib64, local etc. that will also contain other things on the / prefix in a typical linux system.